# Time conversion 12h format 24h format

Tags: python-3.x, class

```
def timeconversion(s):
    #split the time into hours, minutes
    hours, minutes, indicator = map(int, s[:-2].split(":"))
    int(hours)
    int(minutes)
    if indicator == "PM":
        if  hours != 12:
            hours += 12
    elif indicator == "AM" and hours == 12:
        hours = 0
    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_instring = input("enter: ")
    result = timeconversion(input_instring)
    print(result)
```

input is : 10:10:10PM current output is : 10:10:10 but expected is 22:10:10
what is going on?

Comment: `hours, minutes, indicator = map(int, s[:-2].split(":"))` From this line, you know `indicator` will be an integer.  So it can't possibly be equal to "PM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code lies in the way you're handling the input string and the AM/PM indicator. Let's go through your code and correct it step by step.

*String Parsing:* The code splits the input string assuming the format is hours:minutesindicator without a second part. However, your input format is hours:minutes:secondsIndicator. This needs to be adjusted.

*Indicator Handling:* You are trying to convert the indicator to an integer, which will fail since it's either "AM" or "PM".

*Redundant Conversions:* The int(hours) and int(minutes) lines after the map function are redundant because map(int, ...) already converts them to integers.

Here is the corrected version of your function:

```
def time_conversion(s):
    # Split the time into hours, minutes, seconds, and indicator
    time_parts = s[:-2].split(":")
    hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time_parts)
    indicator = s[-2:]

    # Convert hours in case of PM and AM
    if indicator.upper() == "PM" and hours != 12:
        hours += 12
    elif indicator.upper() == "AM" and hours == 12:
        hours = 0

    return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes, seconds)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_string = input("Enter time (HH:MM:SSAM/PM): ")
    result = time_conversion(input_string)
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The line below is providing you hours, minutes and seconds, not hours, minutes and indicator.

```
hours, minutes, indicator = map(int, s[:-2].split(":"))
```

You will need to slice the string differently to get the indicator.

```
hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, s[:-2].split(":"))
indicator = s[-2:]
```